# Spherical coordinates into rectangular coordinates, and then triple integral.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, spherical-coordinates, jacobian

I am trying to evaluate the following triple integral below, $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{3}\rho^2\sin\phi \, \mathrm{d}\rho \, \mathrm{d}\theta \, \mathrm{d}\phi,$$

which is written in spherical coordinates.
But as I am solving the integral, I noticed that
$$\rho^2\sin\phi \, \mathrm{d}\rho \, \mathrm{d}\theta \, \mathrm{d}\phi=\mathrm{d}V = \mathrm{d}z \, \mathrm{d}y \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
So I thought that maybe this triple integral problem can be solved much simply when converted into rectangular coordinates, which would look similar to the mathematical form below.
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\int_{y_1}^{y_2}\int_{z_1}^{z_2}1 \, \mathrm{d}z \, \mathrm{d}y \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
The thing is I have trouble finding the boundaries for each $z$-axis, $y$-axis, and $x$-axis. What should be the appropriate values for $(x_1,x_2), (y_1,y_2), (z_1,z_2)$?

P.S: I am not so comfortable with LaTex yet. I would appreciate any edits to my question. Thank you.

Comment: You have a slice of a sphere of radius $3$ What's the ratio of $\frac{\pi}{6}$ to $2\pi$? Multiply that by the volume of a sphere of radius $3$ and you are done. If you must do the integral it makes little sense to convert it to rectangular coordinates.

Comment: Yes. I know that the question could just be solved by 'What's the ratio of 6 to 2? Multiply that by the volume of a sphere of radius 3 and you are done'. I just to want to see how the triple integral boundaries change when I convert them into rectangular coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spherical is the easier calculation.  Even if you convert to cartesian, you are going to need a trig substitution which effectively puts you back into polar coord's if not spherical...

Anyway, learning how to transform coordinates is important.  I like to try to visualize the region before I start working out.

The region is one-quarter of a cone inside a sphere.

It is one quater of a cone because $0\le \theta\le \frac {\pi}{2}$

The equation for the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 3^2$

The slope of the cone associates with the angle $\frac {\pi}{6}$

$(z\tan \frac {\pi}{6})^2= x^2+y^2$ or $z^2 = 3x^2 + 3y^2$

The intersection of the sphere and the cone is $x^2+y^2 = \frac {9}{4}, z=\frac {3\sqrt 3}{2}$

Okay, that is enough information to make our change of coordinates.

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac 32}\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac 94 - x^2}}\int_{\sqrt {3x^2 + 3y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}\ dz\ dy\ dx$

Comment: The upper limit for $y$ should be $\sqrt{\frac 94 - x^2}$

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks.

Comment: @DougM Thank you so much sir. This question bugged me for few days and I finally got it! Thank you.